# Retrieve the child's data from the parent's data in React JS DataGrid using Firebase real-time database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, datagrid

I want to retrieve and show all the child's or children's data from the parent element. In the context of the photo below, the parent data is a user's unique ID, and nested to it are the user's data, **which the user's data is what I'm trying to display to React JS `DataGrid`**.

[image]

[image]

### The Problem

The problem is that I'm unsure whether the issue comes from React JS "DataGrid" error where it says:

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, 3pIKG2zT0cRS0fQLdmHtONEh1y42. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Or the code I used to read the Data, code below:

```js
export const TbcData = () => {
  const [tbcData, setTbcData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tbcRef = ref(db, "/Nazareth_TBC_Contributions/");
    const readData = onValue(tbcRef, (snapshot) => {

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            const childData = childSnapshot.val();

            setTbcData(Object.values(childData));
        });
    });
    return () => {
        readData(); // return to prevent memory leak
    };
}, []);
```

My `DatGrid`:

```
<div className="dataTable">
    <div className="dataTableTitle">Pending Contributions</div>
    <div style={{ height: 600, width: "100%" }}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%" }}>
            <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <DataGrid
                    rows={tbcData.map((user, index) => {
                        return {
                            ...user,
                            list: index + 1,
                        };
                    })}
                    columns={TbcTableSource.concat(actionColumn)}
                    pageSize={9}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
                    // getRowId={(row) => rows.id}
                    // experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### What I've Tried

Although I managed to display all the children's or the user's data on the `DataGrid`, even if there's an error from above, however, the table shows duplicated values; it copies or duplicates the last data added. See the photo below:

[image]